# JavaScript function nearest geographical neighbor

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am looking for a JavaScript function who returns the nearest neighbor of a number. e.g: I am having a coordinate 12,323432/12,234223 and i want to know the nearest coordinate of a set of 20 other coordinates in a database. 
How to handle that?

Comment: If you don't have a spatial DB with the appropriate functions, you can "manually" compute the distances between all coordinate pairs and take the smallest one.

Comment: Why don't do it in sql?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far, to accomplish this task.

Comment: i´ve done nothing in code so far. Igor S how it´s possible to do this in SQL?

Comment: install [postgis](http://postgis.net/) on your db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following 3 functions find the nearest coordinate from a javascript array using the [**Haversine**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula.

```
function toRad(Value) {
    /** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}

function haversine(lat1,lat2,lng1,lng2){
    rad = 6372.8; // for km Use 3961 for miles
    deltaLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
    deltaLng = toRad(lng2-lng1);
    lat1 = toRad(lat1);
    lat2 = toRad(lat2);
    a = Math.sin(deltaLat/2) * Math.sin(deltaLat/2) + Math.sin(deltaLng/2) * Math.sin(deltaLng/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    return  rad * c;
}
function calculate(){
    var result = haversine(lat1,coordArray [0][0],lng1,coordArray [0][1]);
        for (var i=1;i<coordArray.length;i++){ 
        var ans = haversine(lat1,coordArray [i][0],lng1,coordArray [i][1]);
        if (ans < result){//nearest 
            result = ans;
        }       
    }
    document.write("Result " +result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Less rounding errors with the Vincenty formula

The Haversine formula [suffers from rounding errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Computational_formulas) for the special (and somewhat unusual) case of antipodal points (on opposite ends of the sphere).

A better choice is therefore [the Vincenty formula for the special case of a sphere.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Computational_formulas) It is computationally not more demanding, but suffers less from machine rounding errors.

Here is my Python3 implementation, which runs in any browser using [Brython](https://brython.info) or which one can easily manually transcode to JavaScript:

```
from math import radians, sin, cos, atan2, sqrt


def vincenty_sphere(lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2):

    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    delta_lon = radians(lon2-lon1)

    term1 = (cos(lat2) * sin(delta_lon))**2
    term2 = (cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(delta_lon))**2
    numerator = sqrt(term1 + term2)

    denominator = sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(delta_lon)

    central_angle = atan2(numerator, denominator) 

    radius = 6372.8    # km

    return radius * central_angle


def station_near(geo):

    lat = geo['latitude']
    lon = geo['longitude']

    nearest = 40042.0    # km
    for s in range(len(STATIONS)):
        distance = vincenty_sphere(lat, STATIONS[s].lat, lon, STATIONS[s].lon)
        if(distance < nearest):
            nearest = distance
            station = s

    return station
```